# Почему быстрее обработать отсортированный массив чем несортированный?

Tags: java, c++, оптимизация, производительность

Вот часть C++ кода, который кажется мне довольно странным. По какой-то причине, сортировка данных делает код почти в шесть раз быстрее:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
    int data[arraySize];

    for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        data[c] = std::rand() % 256;


    std::sort(data, data + arraySize);


    clock_t start = clock();
    long long sum = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {

        for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        {
            if (data[c] >= 128)
                sum += data[c];
        }
    }

    double elapsedTime = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout << elapsedTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

Без станд :: Sort (данные, данные + ArraySize);, код выполняется в 11,54 секунды. С отсортированных данных, код выполняется в 1,93 секунды.

Сперва я думал, что это может быть особенностью языка или компилятор аномалией. Так что я попробовал написать подобный код в Java. Результат похож, хоть и менее экстремальный:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        int arraySize = 32768;
        int data[] = new int[arraySize];

        Random rnd = new Random(0);
        for (int c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
            data[c] = rnd.nextInt() % 256;


        Arrays.sort(data);


        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {

            for (int c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
            {
                if (data[c] >= 128)
                    sum += data[c];
            }
        }

        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000.0);
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

Моя первая мысль была, что сортировка записывает данные в кэш, но потом я подумал, что это глупо, ведь массив просто генерируется.

Почему отсортированный массив быстрее обрабатывать чем несортированный?

---

*Данный вопрос является переводом «[Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/2553424)»*