# Почему отсортированный массив обрабатывается быстрее, чем не отсортированный?

Tags: java, c++, оптимизация, производительность, микроархитектура

Вот пример C++ кода, который выглядит очень странно. Почему-то, когда данные отсортированы код выполняется почти в шесть раз быстрее.

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    // Заполнение данными
    const unsigned arraySize = 32768;
    int data[arraySize];

    for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        data[c] = std::rand() % 256;

    // !!! С этой строкой следующий цикл работает быстрее
    std::sort(data, data + arraySize);

    // Проверка
    clock_t start = clock();
    long long sum = 0;

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        // Основной цикл
        for (unsigned c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
        {
            if (data[c] >= 128)
                sum += data[c];
        }
    }

    double elapsedTime = static_cast<double>(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    std::cout << elapsedTime << std::endl;
    std::cout << "sum = " << sum << std::endl;
}
```

- Без `std::sort(data, data + arraySize);`, код выполняется 11.54 секунды.
- С отсортированными данными - 1.93 секунды.

Сначала, я думал что-то не так с языком или компилятором. Поэтому я попробовал использовать Java.

```java
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Заполнение данными
        int arraySize = 32768;
        int data[] = new int[arraySize];

        Random rnd = new Random(0);
        for (int c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
            data[c] = rnd.nextInt() % 256;

        // !!! С этой строкой следующий цикл работает быстрее
        Arrays.sort(data);

        // Проверка
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        {
            // Основной цикл
            for (int c = 0; c < arraySize; ++c)
            {
                if (data[c] >= 128)
                    sum += data[c];
            }
        }

        System.out.println((System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000.0);
        System.out.println("sum = " + sum);
    }
}
```

В итоге получились похожие результаты, но с меньшим разрывом.

---

Первая мысль была о том, что при сортировке данные попадают в кэш, но потом я подумал, что это глупо, потому что массив был только что создан.

- Что происходит?
- Почему отсортированный массив обрабатывается быстрее, чем не отсортированный?

---

<sub>Перевод вопроса [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array

Comment: Обсуждение <s>этого</s> другого вопроса на Мете: [Что делать с вопросами и ответами, переведёнными машинным способом?](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/4748/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53509/discussion-on-question-by-grundy-----).

Answer (score 81, accepted):

<sub>Перевод ответа: [@Mysticial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/4279)</sub>

**Вы стали жертвой ошибки [предсказателя переходов](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).**

---

### Что такое Предсказание переходов?

Рассмотрим железнодорожный узел:

[image]
<sub>[Картинка](//commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Entroncamento_do_Transpraia.JPG) Mecanismo, из Wikimedia Commons. Используется под лицензией [CC-By-SA 3.0](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/deed.en).</sub>

Теперь представим, что мы вернулись в XIX век – до изобретения радио.

Вы - оператор железнодорожного узла и слышите что прибывает поезд. У Вас нет идей по какому пути он должен идти. вы останавливаете поезд и спрашиваете машиниста куда ему нужно. И затем устанавливаете переключатель в нужное положение.

*Поезда тяжелые и с большой инерцией. Поэтому начало движения и остановка занимают много времени.*

Есть ли способ лучше? Вы можете угадать куда пойдет поезд!

- Если угадали верно, поезд продолжит движение не останавливаясь.
- Если ошиблись, машинист остановит поезд, вернется назад, и наорет на Вас, чтобы вы перевели пути. Затем он может продолжить движение.

**Если каждый раз угадывать правильно**, поезд никогда не остановится.
**Если ошибаться очень часто**, поезд будет терять много времени на остановку, возврат, и разгон.

---

**Рассмотрим if-statement:** на уровне процессора - это инструкция ветвления:

[image]

Вы процессор и вы видите ветвление. У Вас нет предположений какая ветка будет выбрана. Что Вам делать? Вы останавливаете выполнение и ждете завершение предыдущей инструкции. Затем вы продолжаете выполнение по правильному пути.

*Современные процессоры сложны и имеют длинные конвейеры. Поэтому "разогрев" и "остановка" занимают много времени.*

Есть ли способ лучше? Вы можете угадать какая ветка будет выполняться!

- Если Вы угадали верно, выполнение продолжится.
- Если ошиблись, необходимо сбросить конвейер и откатиться к ветвлению. Затем можно продолжить с нужной ветки.

**Если каждый раз угадывать правильно**, выполнение никогда не будет останавливаться.
**Если ошибаться очень часто**, будет тратиться много времени на остановку, откат и перезапуск.

---

Это предсказание переходов. Я признаю, это не лучшая аналогия, потому что поезд может указать направление подав сигнал флагом. Но в компьютерах, процессор не знает какое будет выбрано направление до самого последнего момента.

Так какую выбрать стратегию при угадывании. чтобы минимизировать количество раз. когда поезд должен возвращаться и идти по другому пути? Вы можете посмотреть историю! Если поезд идет влево в 99% случаев, тогда догадка будет: налево. Если чередуются, то и догадки тоже чередуются. Если один путь выбирается через каждые три раза, можно предположить то же самое...

***Другими словами, вы пытаетесь определить шаблон поведения и следовать ему.*** Примерно так работает предсказатель переходов.

У большинства приложений хорошо определяемые ветвления. Поэтому у современных предсказателей переходов процент верных догадок обычно составляет >90%. Но когда они сталкиваются с непредсказуемыми ветвями с не определяемыми шаблонами, предсказатели переходов практически бесполезны.

Дальнейшее чтение: ["Предсказатель переходов" статья на Wikipedia](//ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2).

---

### Как указывалось выше, проблема в этом if-statement:

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
    sum += data[c];
```

Обратите внимание, что данные равномерно распределены в диапазоне от 0 до 255.
Когда данные отсортированы, первая половина не будет заходить в if-statement. Затем, в if-statement будут заходить все оставшиеся.

Это очень хорошо для предсказателя, потому что много раз последовательно выбирается одна и та же ветка.
Даже простой счетчик с насыщением правильно предскажет направление, за исключением случая после смены направления.

**Быстрая визуализация:**

```
T = ветка выбрана
N = ветка не выбрана

data[] = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, ... 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, ... 250, 251, 252, ...
branch = N  N  N  N  N  ...   N    N    T    T    T  ...   T    T    T  ...

       = NNNNNNNNNNNN ... NNNNNNNTTTTTTTTT ... TTTTTTTTTT  (легко прогнозировать)
```

Но когда данные случайны, предсказатель бесполезен, потому что он не может предсказать случайные данные.
Таким образом вероятность неверного прогнозирования может быть около 50%. (не лучше чем случайные догадки)

```
data[] = 226, 185, 125, 158, 198, 144, 217, 79, 202, 118,  14, 150, 177, 182, 133, ...
branch =   T,   T,   N,   T,   T,   T,   T,  N,   T,   N,   N,   T,   T,   T,   N  ...

       = TTNTTTTNTNNTTTN ...   (полностью случайно - тяжело прогнозировать)
```

---

**Итак, что можно сделать?**

Если компилятор не может оптимизировать выбор ветки, Вы можете попробовать использовать несколько хаков, если вы готовы пожертвовать читаемостью ради производительности.

Заменить:

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
    sum += data[c];
```

на:

```
int t = (data[c] - 128) >> 31;
sum += ~t & data[c];
```

Это устраняет ветвление и заменяет его некоторыми битовыми операциями.

<sub>(Обратите внимание, что этот хак не совсем эквивалентен оригинальному условию. Но в данном случае он дает верный результат для всех входящих значений из `data[]`.)</sub>

**Benchmarks: Core i7 920 @ 3.5 GHz**

C++ - Visual Studio 2010 - x64 Release

```
//  Ветвление - случайно
seconds = 11.777

//  Ветвление - сортировано
seconds = 2.352

//  Без ветвления - случайно
seconds = 2.564

//  Без ветвления - сортировано
seconds = 2.587
```

Java - Netbeans 7.1.1 JDK 7 - x64

```
//  Ветвление - случайно
seconds = 10.93293813

//  Ветвление - сортировано
seconds = 5.643797077

//  Без ветвления - случайно
seconds = 3.113581453

//  Без ветвления - сортировано
seconds = 3.186068823
```

Наблюдения:

- **С ветвлением:** огромная разница между отсортированными и не отсортированными данными.
- **С хаком:** Нет разницы между сортированными и не сортированными данными.
- В случае C++, при использовании хака результаты немного медленнее, чем при использования ветвления на сортированных данных.

Общее правило заключается в избегании использования условий зависящих от данных в критических циклах. (как в этом примере)

---

**Update :**

- GCC 4.6.1 с `-O3` или `-ftree-vectorize` на x64 возможно генерировать CMOV инструкции. В этом случае нет разницы между сортированными или не отсортированными данными - оба случая быстрые.
- VC++ 2010 не доступно генерирование CMOV для ветвления даже при использовании `/Ox`.
- Intel Compiler 11 делает что-то удивительное. Он [меняет местами два цикла](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_interchange), тем самым поднимая непредсказуемое ветвление во внешний цикл. Так что становится не только не восприимчивым к ошибкам предсказания, но и в два раза быстрее чем VC++ и GCC могут сгенерировать! Другими словами, ICC воспользовался тестовыми циклами для победы над тестом...
- Если Вы даете Intel Compiler код без ветвления, он векторизует его... и это так же быстро, как и с ветвлением (со сменой циклов).

Это показывает, что даже зрелые компиляторы могут отличаться друг от друга в их способности оптимизировать код...

Comment: А немного жаль, что с уверенной победой hyperthreading, speculative execution (это когда мы начинаем параллельно выполнять команды обоих веток, а потом отбрасываем неактуальные результаты) уже и не упоминается.

Comment: Объяснение как-то "притянуто за уши". Если до этого было 128 N-ветвлений, а в 129 раз T, почему в 130-200 раза процессор должен выбрать T? Ведь всё это время процент N-срабатываний выше, значит прогнозироваться должно постоянно N! т.е. прогнозирование будет работать только в первой половине отсортированных данных, а во второй половине всё пойдёт крахом?

Comment: @Isaev, в ответе нет описания алгоритмов для предсказания. Примеры различный вариаций можно увидеть по ссылке на википедию. Собственно сама реализация предсказателя не очень важна в данном вопросе/ответе.

Answer (score 15):

Данный эффект скорее всего возникает из-за наличия [блока предсказаний переходов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2) процессора. Когда данные отсортированы, ветвление в

```
if (data[c] >= 128)
```

меняется только один раз (сначала условие не срабатывает, а потом всегда срабатывает), и предсказание работает лучше. На неотсортированной последовательности сложнее предугадать сработает `if` или нет. Если убрать `if` вовсе, можно заметить, что наличие или отсутствие `sort` никак не влияет на длительность вычислений.

P.S. Код ТС, по видимому, заимствован из [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11227809/3240681) на enSO. Так что за более детальным описанием можете пройти по ссылке. Мой ответ не является переводом, о чём я уже указал в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623285/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9/623290#comment869052_623290).

Comment: [Полезная ссылка](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11227902/4279)

Comment: @jfs да. Уже отписывался в комментах под вопросом. Что-то коммент потёрли.

Comment: Подобную ссылку стоит в ваш ответ явно включить (учитывая что вы тот же подход описываете и качество исходника).

Comment: @jfs я на самом деле, хотя оригинальный вопрос и видел уже раньше. Но когда писал ответ, совершенно об этом забыл, т.е. нельзя сказать, что идея заимствована, хотя на первоисточник я и не претендую.

Answer (score 7):

Вы наблюдаете работу **предсказателя переходов**. Это устройство, входящее в состав процессоров, и имеющих конвейерную архитектуру, предсказывающее, будет ли выполнен условный переход в исполняемой программе.

С отсортированного массива, данные `data[c] >= 128` меняются один раз для полосы значений и становятся верным для всех последующих значений. Их легко предсказать процессору (*точность предсказания переходов в современных процессорах превышает 90%*). С несортированным массивом, вы платите скоростью работы программы за разветвления.

Без предсказания переходов конвейер должен дождаться выполнения инструкции условного перехода, чтобы произвести следующую выборку. Предсказатель переходов позволяет избежать траты времени, пытаясь выяснить ответвление.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, при сортировке массив `data` попал в кэш процессора. Есть учесть небольшой размер массива, то он должен целиком попасть в 1 кэш линию.

- [Кэш_процессора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%8D%D1%88_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Comment: Не в кэше дело вовсе.

Comment: Только что сгенерированный и не сортированный массив также будет в кэше.

Answer (score -2):

Очень странный ответ на вопрос, вернее ответ на другой вопрос, или ответ на вопрос, который и не спрашивали. Какое отношение сортировка и предсказание ветвлений имеют друг к другу? На самом деле - они злейшие враги. Сортировка - это кошмар для блока предсказания.

Давайте сначала разберём ответ. Он демонстрирует наличие у современных процессоров предсказания ветвлений и работу этого алгоритма, причём пример выбран неудачно: давайте повторим сто тысяч раз одно и тоже! Да, сто тысяч повторений и блок предсказания - явные большие друзья. Попробуйте найти другой, полезный пример того, как нужно проектировать алгоритм решения задачи для его эффективной работы с предсказанием ветвлений.

Теперь перейдём к вопросу и предложим варианты ответа. Сортировка или другие виды упорядочивания, например, хэширование, могут существенно ускорить решение задачи. В данном случае нужно было сделать так с отсортированным массивом:

```
int j = 0; for (; j < N & MyArray[j] < 128; j++); for (int k = j; k < N; k++) sum += MyArray[k];
```

Сортировка помогла избавиться от лишних проверок. Для однократного применения выигрыша, конечно, никакого, но решение многих задач может существенно упроститься.

Что ещё есть полезного в этом топике? Упоминание приёма изменения порядка вложенности циклов. Его не обязательно оставлять на откуп оптимизирующему компилятору.

Вот пример:

```
using System;
namespace ArraySortBrachPredictionTestTask{
    class ArraySortBrachPredictionTest{
        static void Main(string[] args){
            var Rand = new Random(); const int N = 32768 * 8192; var MyArray = new int[N]; int sum;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) MyArray[i] = Rand.Next(256);
            var watch = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch(); watch.Start();
            sum = 0; int j = 0; for (; j < N; j++) if (MyArray[j] >= 128) sum += MyArray[j];
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} without sort\r\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            Array.Sort(MyArray);
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine("Sorting takes {0}\r\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            sum = 0; for (j = 0; j < N; j++) if (MyArray[j] >= 128) sum += MyArray[j];
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} with sort\r\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
            watch.Reset(); watch.Start();
            sum = 0; for (j = 0; j < N & MyArray[j] < 128; j++);
            for (int k = j; k < N; k++) sum += MyArray[k];
            watch.Stop(); Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time {0} with sort and less if\r\n", watch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0);
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты:

Elapsed time 1,253 without sort

Sorting takes 14,164

Elapsed time 0,322 with sort

Elapsed time 0,256 with sort and less if

Да, видим работу предсказателя ветвлений. Только создание благоприятных для него условий заняло уж слишком много времени.

В общем, наскоком выгоду не получишь. Нужно решать задачу эффективно.

Comment: больше похоже на комментарий чем на ответ. Как текст в твоем ответе связан с вопросом: _почему в случае с отсортированным массивом выполнение осуществлялось быстрее?_ Если это был комментарий к какому-то из ответов, нужно было оставлять как комментарий.

Comment: imho пример как раз хорошо демонстрирует работу предсказания переходов. Обратите внимание, массив заполняется случайными числоми от 0 до 256. Половина меньше 128, а половина больше. После сортировки в первой половине массива мы суммирем, а во второй ничего не делаем. Собственно, именно эффективность этого выбора и обеспечивает предсказатель, что прекрасно демонстрирует время выполнения программы. Ну а внешний цикл нужен лишь для наглядной демонстрации этой разницы во времени выполнения.

Comment: Не понятно с кем вы спорите по поводу медленной сортировки, если никто и не говорил, что она быстрая? Использование сортировки в вопросе лишь способ получения сортированного массива. С тем же успехом ТС мог заполнить первую половину массива значениями вида `rand() % 128`, а вторую `rand() % 128 + 128;`.