# Время выполнения сортировки

Tags: java, алгоритм

Имеется алгоритм сортировки пузырьком:

```
public Info sort(ArrayList<Comparable> list) {
    Info info = new Info();
    info.countItems = list.size();

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    boolean run = true;
    int bound = list.size();
    while(run) {
        run = false;
        for(int i = 0; i + 1 < bound; i++) {
            Comparable a = list.get(i);
            Comparable b = list.get(i + 1);
            info.countEquals++;
            if(a.compareTo(b) > 0) {
                Comparable temp = a;
                list.set(i, b);
                list.set(i + 1, temp);
                run = true;
                info.countReplace++;
            }
        }
        bound--;
    }
    info.millis = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;

    return info;
}
```

Класс хранящий информацию о кол-во проверок, перестановок и времени выполнения:

```
public class Info {

    public long millis;
    public long countReplace;
    public long countEquals;
    public long countItems;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Info{" +
            "millis=" + millis +
            ", countReplace=" + countReplace +
            ", countEquals=" + countEquals +
            ", countItems=" + countItems +
            '}';
    }
}
```

Заполнение массива и выполнение сортировки:

```
    java.util.ArrayList<Comparable> list = new java.util.ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++) list.add(i);
    Collections.shuffle(list);
    System.out.println(new BubbleSort().sort(list));
    list.clear();
    for(int i = 100000; i >= 0; i--) list.add(i);
    System.out.println(new BubbleSort().sort(list));
```

Результат:

```
Info{millis=131839, countReplace=2496512553, countEquals=4999942374, 
countItems=100000} //массив был заполнен случайными не повторяющимеся значениями
Info{millis=94886, countReplace=5000050000, countEquals=5000050000, 
countItems=100000} //значения до сортировки шли в убывающем порядке
```

Как видно - для второго случая число проверок и кол-во перестановок больше, чем в первом, но время выполнения значительно меньше. Собственно вопрос: с чем это может быть связано?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623435/276430

Comment: Спасибо. Вопрос можно считать закрытым.