# Хочу спросить о движке JavaScript в for loop цикле [действия выполнялись в браузере chrome]

Tags: javascript, оптимизация, for

Когда я написал данный скрипт:

```
const t = new Date()

for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  const p = 10000000
  for (let _ = 0; _ < 10; _++) BigInt(p)
}

console.log(new Date()-t);
```

То хром браузер выдавал ~100 (мс), но когда я меняю на:

```
const t = new Date()

for (let i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
  const p = i
  for (let _ = 0; _ < 10; _++) BigInt(p)
}

console.log(new Date()-t);
```

браузер хром стал выдавать ~3200 (мс)

**Вопрос** - почему когда я использую **i** код замедляется.

Comment: в каком браузере ты пробовал?

Comment: Chrome_______________

Comment: Одно только угадывание предсказателем ветвлений процессора правильного пути выполнения кода может давать [многократный прирост производительности](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/623435). В первом скрипте всегда конвертируется одно и то же число `p`, а во втором скрипте число `p` регулярно меняется. Кто знает на каком из множества слоёв абстракций это выльется в падение производительности. И выльется ли. В моём «браузере хром» разница в несколько процентов. Так что хотя бы версию браузера уточните.

Comment: chrome 115.0.5790.110

Comment: сделай профилирование на вкладке Performance  в  dev tools.

Comment: Потому что оптимизатор вынес `BigInt(p)` из цикла. Выражение константное, зачем мучаться вычисляя его сто миллионов раз?