# merge sort на рандомных числах работает в 2 раза дольше, чем должен

Tags: c++, сортировка, сортировка-слиянием

Написал сортировку слиянием без рекурсии. Протестил. Работает, сортирует, исключения не бросает, за границы массива не лезет. Был доволен и счастлив, пока не решил проверить теорию о том, что на любых входных данных эта сортировка работает одинаковое количество времени. И вот тут обнаружился интересный момент.

Пока я сам писал условия заполнения массива - всё было нормально. Пробовал от 0 до размера массива (`array[i] = i`), от размера до нуля (`array[i] = size - i`), от нуля до размера с чередованием знака, от нуля до размера с *рандомными* знаками, весь массив одним числом, половина массива одним числом и вторая половина другим... Всё выдавало +- одинаковые результаты, ~115мс для 1млн чисел. Но вот когда попробовал заполнять массив полностью рандомом, `array[i] = std::rand()`, то время выполнения сортировки резко подскочило почти в два раза - до 190мс и выше.

Искренне недоумеваю, почему так выходит. Строки с заполнением массива, разумеется, не входят в диапазон отслеживаемого по длительности выполнения кода. Алгоритм сортировки пока что успешно прикидывается правильным. Ради эксперимента добавлял счётчики во все циклы в функции сортировки, чтобы отслеживать количество их проходов - как и ожидалось, для одного размера массива сумма значений счётчиков была одинаковой при любых входных данных... А время выполнения всё равно разное. Как так?

Код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// собственно сортировка
void mergeSort(int array[], size_t arraySize) {
    int *newArray = new int[arraySize];
    for (int i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
        newArray[i] = array[i];
    }

    size_t size = 1;
    while (size < arraySize) {
        size_t currentPos = 0;
        for (size_t startPos = 0; startPos < arraySize; startPos += 2 * size) {
            size_t left = startPos, right = startPos + size;
            if (right >= arraySize) {           // если у левой части массива нет "пары" для сравнения
                break;
            }
            while (left < startPos + size && right < (startPos + 2*size) && right < arraySize) {
                if (array[left] <= array[right]) {
                    newArray[currentPos] = array[left];
                    left++;
                }
                else {
                    newArray[currentPos] = array[right];
                    right++;
                }
                currentPos++;
            }
            // если left/right дошёл до границы, добавляем оставшиеся элементы из другой части массива
            while (left < startPos + size) {
                newArray[currentPos] = array[left];
                currentPos++;
                left++;
            }
            while (right < (startPos + 2 * size) && right < arraySize) {
                newArray[currentPos] = array[right];
                currentPos++;
                right++;
            }
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < arraySize; i++) {
            array[i] = newArray[i];
        }
        size *= 2;
    }
    delete[] newArray;
}

// функция для замера времени выполнения
long long timeTest(int array[], size_t size) {
    auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    mergeSort(array, size);
    auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

// тесты
int main() {
    std::srand(std::time(0));
    // параметры тестирования: количество элементов массива и прогонов для получения среднего значения
    size_t size = 1000000;
    size_t nTests = 10;

    int* array = new int[size];
    size_t linearTime = 0, randomTime = 0;
    for (size_t test = 0; test < nTests; test++) {
        // от 0 до размера массива
        for (size_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            array[i] = i;
        }
        linearTime += timeTest(array, size);

        // рандомные числа
        for (size_t i = 0; i <= size - 1; i++) {
            array[i] = std::rand();
        }
        randomTime += timeTest(array, size);
    }

    std::cout << "Linear: " << (int)(linearTime / nTests) << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Random: " << (int)(randomTime / nTests) << "ms" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод после запуска:

```
Linear: 108ms
Random: 196ms
```

Comment: На случайных данных предсказатель переходов перестаёт работать. На уровне процессора выполнение циклов с условными переходами замедляется. Вы можете придумать не случайный массив с таким же свойством. Это хорошее понимание на то как устроена сортировка слиянием.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, перенесите комментарий в ответ (он того стоит)

Comment: [Почему отсортированный массив обрабатывается быстрее, чем не отсортированный?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/626264)